# How to produce double images using Tkinter?

Tags: python, image, loops, tkinter

I am quite new to python and tkinter and this is my code, I am trying to create a spin machine game and I have gotten stuck on this bit, it produces the correct amount of images that I want it to (three), when there are only single times its come up, but when my code that decides which image should be put up decides two show two of the same image the code glitches up and only shows 1 out of the two no matter what I have tried, I tried assigning it to a list then showing it again but that didn't work as I dont think I did it correctly. Any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated,  and an explanation would go a long way.
BTW I have attached all image files to the pycharm project.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import random

global COLUMN
COLUMN = 0



def click1():
    SpinSigns = ["Banana", "Bell", "Cherry", "Dollar", "Skull"]
    BananaCounter = 0
    BellCounter = 0
    CherryCounter = 0
    DollarCounter = 0
    SkullCounter = 0

    global COLUMN
    COLUMN = 0

    for i in range(3):

        doubles = []
        randomSign = SpinSigns[random.randint(0,4)]

        if randomSign == "Banana":
            global banana
            banana = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("BananaSign.png"))
            Banana = Label(window, image=banana)
            Banana.grid(row=0, column= COLUMN)
            BananaCounter += 1
            print(randomSign)
            if BananaCounter == 2:
                doubles.append(Banana)
                doubles[0].grid(row = 0, column = 4)


        elif randomSign == "Bell":
            global bell
            bell = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("BellSign.png"))
            Bell = Label(window, image=bell)
            Bell.grid(row=0, column= COLUMN)
            BellCounter += 1
            print(randomSign)
            if BellCounter == 2:
                doubles.append(Bell)
                doubles[0].grid(row = 0, column = 4)

        elif randomSign == "Cherry":
            global cherry
            cherry = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("CherrySign.png"))
            Cherry = Label(window, image=cherry)
            Cherry.grid(row=0, column= COLUMN)
            print(randomSign)
            CherryCounter += 1
            if CherryCounter == 2:
                doubles.append(Cherry)
                doubles[0].grid(row = 0, column = 4)



        elif randomSign == "Dollar":
            global dollar
            dollar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("DollarSign.png"))
            Dollar = Label(window, image=dollar)
            Dollar.grid(row=0, column= COLUMN)
            DollarCounter += 1
            print(randomSign)
            if DollarCounter == 2:
                doubles.append(Dollar)
                doubles[0].grid(row = 0, column = 4)


        elif randomSign == "Skull":
            global skull
            skull = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("SkullSign.png"))
            Skull = Label(window, image=skull)
            Skull.grid(row=0, column= COLUMN)
            SkullCounter += 1
            print(randomSign)
            if SkullCounter == 2:
                doubles.append(Skull)
                doubles[0].grid(row = 0, column = 4)
        COLUMN += 1


window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x450")
lever = Button(window, text="Pull Me!", command = click1)


# coins = Label(text=coinAmount)
# coins.grid(row = 0, column = 0)




#label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

lever.grid(row=1, column= 1)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you reset `doubles` to empty list in each iteration?

Comment: When there is image selected twice, the first image will be garbage collected because same global variable is used for the two images.  Also the second image is moved to row 0 column 4, so there is only one image shown for that *double images*.